# Why I am getting number of bound variables does not match number of tokens error message?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating a dynamic function to insert data to the database using PHP PDO.

Here is the function in the `Database` Class.

```
public function insert ( $table, $feilds = array() ) {

    $key    = array_keys($feilds);
    $column = implode(',', $key);

    $ques   = array();

    foreach ($feilds as $value) {
        $ques[] = " ?";
    }

    $ques = implode(', ', $ques);   

    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $table( $column ) VALUES ( $ques )");

    $x=1;       
    foreach ($feilds as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam($x, $var);
        $var =  $value;
        $stmt->execute();           
        $x++;
    }       
}
```

I am inserting data like this:

```
$data = array(
    'b_title'   =>  'My blog title', 
    'b_des'     =>  'My blog description',
);
$database->insert('blog', $data);
```

But when I run this query it's saying

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of token

I don't understand where the bound variable and token is not matched! How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt->execute();` should go outside the foreach

Comment: OH, I'm blind :(

Comment: it happens to everyone :P